# Chrome Password Manager: How to add password manually?

Tags: google-chrome, passwords

I´d like to add a password for a site into the Chrome Password Manager, but Chrome doesn´t offer a save button (i.e. it doesn´t recognise the password field). So I´d like to add the password manually. I know there will be no automatic fill-in if Chrome doesn´t even recognise the field as password field, but at least I´d know where to look for it...

I´d like to ask how to do it, but following uncle google´s answer my question is: **is it possible?**

Comment: This first comment in [this answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59989224/4742733) worked for me.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1519402/how-can-i-manually-add-a-password-to-chrome-password-manager

Answer (score 50, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to use Chrome's **Password import**, which lets you import entries for Chrome's Password Manager from a [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file.

Note that the feature is an experimental feature, and must be **explicitly enabled**. How to do this depends on the version:

- As of Chrome 79 (December 2019), go to chrome://flags/, find the setting "Password import", set to "Enable", restart Chrome.
- As of Chrome 93 (August 2021), you must start Chrome with the command line parameter `--enable-features=PasswordImport` instead (the setting under chrome://flags/ no longer exists). See [Issue 1021518: Chrome FR: Import Password not available in settings on Chrome78](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1021518)  in the Chromium bug tracker for details.

Then, to add an entry to the password manager:

- Create a CSV file for the entry. The first line lists the columns, then each line represents one password manager entry, with the site name, username and password. The file will look like this:

  ```
    name,url,username,password
    example.org,https://example.org/,user,secret
    example2.org,https://example2.org/,anotheruser,extrasecret
    [...]
  ```

The easiest way to get it right is probably to export your existing passwords to a file, under "Settings" / "Saved Passwords" / "Export passwords" (in the overflow menu). Then edit the resulting CSV file using a text editor. Make sure to set the editor to use UTF-8 text encoding.

- Import the CSV file, using "Import" (also in the overflow menu in the Password Manager).
- Note that "Import" will *add* entries to your database. So it's safe to create a CSV file with just the new entries you want to add, and import it. Your existing entries will remain. Exception: I believe if you import an entry for a site that already has an entry, import will overwrite it.

---

**Alternative: Manage passwords using your Google account**

If you have a Google account, and you have [enabled "sync" in Google Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/185277), you can also manage your saved passwords in your Google account (under https://passwords.google.com/options ).

This may be easier than modifying command line parameters and working with a text file; however, sync (and Google accounts in general) have many privacy implications, so you will have to decide whether the convenience is worth it for you.

<sub>Thanks to Omkar Rajam for mentioning this.</sub>

Comment: @Stavros: I removed your edit stating "note that you will not get any warnings related to failure" since the sentence does not make sense (what warnings? what failure?). If you can explain what you want to warn about, feel free to comment here so it can be incorporated into the answer :-).

Comment: Not working for me.  I don't get any options for the chrome flags to enable password importing.  I can only export.

Comment: @DRK: Did you read my (updated) answer? Did you try command line parameter --enable-features=PasswordImport ?

Comment: I'm unable to get the "Import" button to show either in the password manager or in `chrome://settings/passwords`.  I even restarted Chrome with the `--enable-features=PasswordImport` option -- and I was able to check `PasswordImport` under `chrome://flags/#PasswordImport` as well.

Comment: @JosiahYoder: Just re-checked - I must enable it under "chrome://flags/", as described, then it works. Tested in Chrome 84 on Win and Linux. Strange that is does not work for you...

Comment: @sleske It works for me now! I now see it in `chrome://settings/passwords`.  I think I didn't reboot Chrome correctly. I rebooted for another reason, and that would, of course, force a restart of Chrome. Though still unclear why manually launching from the command line didnt work!

Comment: I would just add that the url has to be a valid url otherwise the parser seems to ignore the line

Comment: Seems like this feature is unavailable in Chrome 93. There is no import menu and no `PasswordImport` flag

Comment: @Finesse: Please read my answer :-). It says that you may need to start Chrome with the command line parameter --enable-features=PasswordImport . If I do that, my Chrome 93 does show the import feature. I edited to clarify.

Comment: @sleske I see that you've added it recently. I've used a solution with `navigator.credentials.store` already.

Comment: @sleske This worked well.  After export I removed all the entries and put in the new ones.  Interestingly, when I had migrated from Firefox it had supposedly imported all passwords.  But this was a lie, many sites did not work.  Worse, for these same sites, it does not offer to save the password.  But when I manually import it as above, it works for these sites.  An example was paypal.com.  So, it has nothing to do with field names.  There is something else going on.

Comment: @sleske If you go to https://passwords.google.com/options, you can see the same CSV based "Export passwords" and "Import passwords" options there. So, if you are someone who is not comfortable in dealing with flags and command line parameters, it is an easier option to go to that site and add passwords.

Comment: @OmkarRajam: Thanks for pointing this out - though this requires being signed into your Google account, and enabling Sync in Chrome. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Seems this functionality has been disabled. Starting browser with `--enable-features=PasswordImport` adds import option, but it does nothing. Using Chromium here.

Comment: @Mauricio: Strange, it still works for me (Chrome 104). Maybe Chromium removed the feature, or is buggy...

Comment: In my current version (117.0.5938.92) of Chrome, there's a UI options to import passwords (see: chrome://password-manager/settings)

Answer (score 12):

As stated here https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/PasswordCredential.
Visit the site you want to save passwords on, open the dev tool and type :

```js
const cred = new PasswordCredential({
  id: '<site user>', // ex: myLoginUser@mail.com
  password: '<site password>',
  name: '<name>',  // how it appears in password manager
});

navigator.credentials.store(cred) // Will prompt you to save the password
 .then(()  => {
   // Do something or not
 });
```

Comment: same, but as one shorter line: 
```navigator.credentials.store(new PasswordCredential({id: '<site user>', password: '<site password>', name: '<name>'})).then(()  => {});```

But it does not works for me...

I have tried ```navigator.credentials.store(new PasswordCredential({id: 'testUser', password: 'qqqwww', name: 'TestUserStoring'})).then(()  => {alert("ok")});``` at this page, and nothing into passwords was added...

Comment: @Nashev Worked for me on Chrome 95.0. For me it showed the usual password manager prompt pre-populated with the values in the script. I was able to edit and save it. So the script doesn't add the password directly on its own.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, Chromium 99 in Ubuntu. Delete your console history after (right click in the console.)

Answer (score 7):

This solution expands on the previous answer but using Google passwords way of importing.

Create a .csv file with your login credentials like this

```
name,url,username,password
example.org,https://example.org/,user,secret
```

And go to https://passwords.google.com/options?ep=1 and login with the same user credentials you used with Chrome and click on Import under Import passwords and go to your page that you're trying to save the password and you should see your password filled, voila!!

Comment: This worked for Chrome 93.0.4577.82 when I needed to save a password for an internal company https site with invalid certificate.

Answer (score 3):

This might not be exactly what you were looking for but I found this useful as the above answer wouldn't work for me (flag appears to be missing) when wanting to save a password for safekeeping.

I hosted [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_password_val) html file on a local web server and typed my username and password in there, then when I need to look for the password I can just search for localhost, you could even put the site address and username in the username field to help you remember which site it is for.

Comment: You could also just add an `<input type="password">` element onto the desired website (with the developer tools) and Chrome adds a small key icon into the navbar and lets you save the password to the actual domain (instead of localhost).

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 Even if the site uses type="password" fields, Chrome does not always recognize them, e.g., https://inkscape.org/user/register/

Comment: @JosiahYoder works in my case. I just opened the page, entered some random password and as soon as the first letter was in the field, the key icon appeared on the top right in Chrome (v84/Windows).

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 Hmmm... you are right. The key appears.  I am wanting it to suggest a random password.  I guess I'm back to [`date +%s | sha256sum | base64 | head -c 32 ; echo`](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/30184/10-ways-to-generate-a-random-password-from-the-command-line/) again.

Comment: @JosiahYoder Right click into the password field might help you. ;)

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 You're right! Why didn't I try that?  Anyhow, after creating an account on this site, I found that in the settings page, it pops up a suggestion to create a strong password automatically.  Not sure what the difference is, but nice to get (another) reminder of how easy strong password suggestions are when the password field is there -- automatic pop-up or not.

Comment: how to add passwords for localhost (Chrome 100+)? Chrome want I'm need to add something like .com .net etc to the domain address

Answer (score 1):

I found an easy way.

- On Desktop:
  Right click to password field and select "suggest password", accept it and save it.
- On Mobile: Tap on the password field so a key icon shows above keyboard, tap the key icon to have google password manager suggest a password and save it.

And then go to password manager on desktop to edit the saved password and replace it with your actual password manually.

Next time you visit the site, you can auto-populate the password.

Note that this requires the field to have type="password"